# How to delete specific values from a column in a dataset (Python)?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a data set as below:

[image]

I want to remove `'Undecided'` from my `['Grad Intention']` column. For this, I created a copy DataFrame and using the code as follows:

`df_copy=df_copy.drop([df_copy['Grad Intention'] =='Undecided'], axis=1)`

However, this is giving me an error.

How can I remove the row with `'Undecided'`? Also, what's wrong with my code?

Comment: `df = df[df['Grad Intention'] != 'Undecided']`

Comment: thanks this worked. But if i try to pass this data frame to construct a cross tab it shows error
Code- pd.crosstab(df.copy['Gender'], df.copy['Grad Intention'])
Error-
TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable

Can you let me know what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

you could simply use:

```
df = df[df['Grad Intention'] != 'Undecided']
or
df.drop(df[df['Grad Intention'] == 'Undecided'].index, inplace = True)
```

Comment: Thanks this worked. But if i try to pass this data frame to construct a cross tab it shows error
Code- pd.crosstab(df.copy['Gender'], df.copy['Grad Intention'])
Error-
TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable

Can you let me know what is going wrong here?